# In-app billing - Android Market

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing

I'm trying implement a In-app billing. I'm with a doubt about constants. What is class have the BILLING_REQUEST, API_VERSION and PACKAGE_NAME constants?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know off-hand, but have you checked out the [sample application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download)? If those constants are needed for in-app billing to work, they should be in there.

Answer (score 2):

These are just strings you could make your own class and reference them from there:

```
public class Constants {

    // These are the names of the fields in the request bundle.
    public static final String BILLING_REQUEST = "BILLING_REQUEST";
    public static final String API_VERSION = "API_VERSION";
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "PACKAGE_NAME";

}
```

They are in the [SampleApplication](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) as stated by @James

Comment: To follow up I've included this in a tutorial: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/